# Enable and disable image in yii

Tags: javascript, yii

In the yii form have a checkbox for agree conditions. The code like this

```
<div class="row">                     
<?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'agree',array('id'=>'abc')); ?>
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'agree'); ?>
<?php echo "<br><br>".$form->error($model,'agree'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row buttons" >
<?php  echo CHtml::imageButton(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/home/Create.png',      array('submit'),array('id'=>'efg'));?></div>
```

I want to disabled image button onload and when check the checkbox, i want to enable the image button. 
How it possible in yii?

Comment: Use Javascript or ajax call.Read the Documentation carefully

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you should:

1. Check the state of the checkbox
2. Depending on this state enable or not the button

Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#abc').click(function () {
        if($('#abc').is(':checked')) {
            $("#efg").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
           $("#efg").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but no more changes using this code. The image always enable mode.

Comment: Hum I have tested the javascript on a simple button : `<button id="efg">Clic</button>` and it's working so could you give us the code generated by CHtml::imageButton so I could test it?

Comment: And for an image you should have a second image representing the disable state no? (Also tested with an image button and the code above is working!)